# Let $X$ be a regular topological space and $A \subset X$. Show that $A$ is also regular.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a regular topological space and $A \subset X$. Show that $A$ is also regular.

So I want to show that for $F \subset A$ closed and $x \in A \setminus F$ I can find two neighborhoods $U_x$ and $U_F$ such that $U_x \cap U_F = \emptyset$.

Let $F$ be a closed subset of $A$ and let $x \in A \setminus F$. Then since $F \subset A \subset X$ $F$ is closed in $X$ and $x \in A \setminus F \subset X$ we can use the regularity of $X$ to find disjoint neighborhoods $V_x$ and $V_F$.

If I know let $U_x = V_x \cap A$ and $U_F=V_F \cap A$ these are both open neighborhoods of $x$ and $F$ respectively and they should be disjoint?

I don't think I'm correct here since I do not use the fact that $F$ being closed in $A$ implies that $F= C \cap A$ for $C$ closed in $X$.

Comment: First you have to ask yourself what does it mean by open or closed in $A$. i.e. what's the topology on $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ closed in $A$ does not imply that it is closed in $X$. For, example $A$ is closed in itself whether or not it is closed in $X$.

We can write $F=A\cap C$ with $C$ closed in $X$. Since $x \notin C$ (because $x \in A$ and $x \notin F$) therv exist disjoint open sets $U,V$ in $X$ such that $x \in U$ and $C \subseteq V$. Now $A\cap U$ and $ A\cap V$ are disjoint open sets in $A$ containing $x$ and $F$  respectively.